# Pancake Electrical Box Nailed To Wall

Tags: electrical, drywall, walls, light-fixture, studs

I'm replacing a wall-mounted light fixture in my 1983 condo and as I was unmounting the fixture I noticed it was a little loose.

I checked out the electrical box and it's a bit loose. You can slightly rotate it. I think actually there are just nails holding the box to the wall. I scraped the paint off them and they look like big metal nail heads. See red circles in this pic:

[image: Electrical box closeup]

I did see [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/208954/how-to-remove-junction-box-that-is-nailed-on) but I don't think it's one of those riveted boxes. I have two studs on either side and then interestingly the stud finder shows something thick running vertically underneath where the box is, maybe 3 or 4" across, see this pic:

[image]

Can I just pull these nails out and replace with lags or "wall dogs" or similar? Or what should I do to ensure this fixture is secure?

Comment: Can use the other holes for screws and leave the nails in place.

Comment: Thanks @crip659 good suggestion but I started thinking I'd to rotate the box like 20° CCW so the cross bar runs vertically (just works better for the fixture I'm installing). Maybe I'll just try pulling the nails and remount the box using screws.

Comment: Pulling nails from boxes is not fun.  If the nails are in the wood good, most nail pullers can damage the box.  Grinding the head off might be easier and/or have a replacement box handy.

Comment: Swivel crossbar is a lot less trouble than pulling nails in my opinion. https://www.amazon.com/Canomo-Universal-Crossbar-Cross-Shaped-Lighting/dp/B0826P4K6H/ref=asc_df_B0826P4K6H

Comment: Thanks crip659 and AloysiusDefenestrate I'll take both your comments under advisement and good to know about swivel crossbars

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is install one more fastener (i.e. screw), and the box will rotate no more, and be adequately secure for any reasonably sized fixture. So if you have any solid backing behind any of the numerous holes in the box, you're all set.

The box is missing any sort of clamp/bushing on the incoming cable, which is required. You can probably find a 5-pack of little plastic snap-in cable clamps, to fit the knock-out hole in your box, at any of the big box "home improvement" stores.

There are light fixture crossbars that have rotating parts to allow mounting the fixture at any angle.

Answer (score 0):

If the box is a little loose, what's the harm? But if you wanted to tighten it, you could tap on the nail heads with a nail set or any suitable rod.

Alternatively you could wipe some epoxy or other glue around and under the nail heads.

Assuming of course that the nails are not loose in the wood.